# Selecting all records created current year with Eloquent

Tags: select, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to select records created at current year, with Eloquent

So far, this is the code I'm using. How can I filter the results to retrieve only the ones created in the current year?

```
public function vacationsbalance($typeId) {
    // Get vacataions balance for existing employee.
    $vacationsBalance = $this->vacations()->where('vacation_type_id', '=', $typeId)->sum('days_num');
    return $vacationsBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have timestamps in your table (that is, you have a `created_at` column with the record's creation date), you can use:

```
public function vacationsbalance($typeId) {
    // Get vacations balance for existing employee and for the current year.
    return $this->vacations()
        ->where('vacation_type_id', '=', $typeId)
        ->whereRaw('year(`created_at`) = ?', array(date('Y')))
        ->sum('days_num');
}
```

Check [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)'s documentation and look for `whereRaw`.